# How do I configure updates for the 64-bit jre7?

Tags: windows-7, java

Good afternoon all,

I've got both the 32-bit jre7 and 64-bit jre7 installed.

In the control panel of the 32-bit jre7 (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javacpl.exe*), there is an "Update" tab where I can configure the updates for the 32-bit jre7:

[image]

However I can't seem to find any way to configure updates for the 64-bit jre7, since the control panel for the 64-bit jre7 (*C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javacpl.exe*) does not have an "Updates" tab:

[image]

Similar question but has no answers: [Java Control Panel does not show Update tab on Windows 7 x64](https://superuser.com/q/275700/78897)

Answer (score 2):

Auto update is not supported for 64-bit Java yet ([bug track](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6492837)). You can track the updates from RSS channel of [Java SE News](https://blogs.oracle.com/javase/category/Oracle/FCS+Release) and download [installation package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) manually.

Comment: Any idea roughly when will it be out?

Comment: I have no idea when it is planned to implement, sorry.

Comment: Has that bug been there since 2006?!? Do the decision-makers at Oracle sleep at night knowing that they foist this crap on the world?