# Control panel applet for Java is missing - How do I get it back?

Tags: windows-7, java

**Update:** This is obviously not a duplicate of the issue where the Java applet is visible in the Control Panel *for the simple reason that the applet in that question actually shows up in the control panel*.

The control panel applet for Java is missing on my Windows 7 Pro (64-bit).

I have Java CPL (control panel item) installed in "Program Files" and "Program-Files" (this second one does not seem to be an actual separate directory however but a link to maybe the first one?)

[image: Java control panel applets]

The Java was installed by myself (I am the only user on this computer).

How can I get the control panel item show up in the control panel, so that I can run it with admin rights?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Control Panel does not show Update tab on Windows 7 x64](http://superuser.com/questions/275700/java-control-panel-does-not-show-update-tab-on-windows-7-x64)

Comment: Hardly a duplicate @Ramhound because the control panel applet actually shows up for that user. You can't use those steps to fix this issue.

Comment: You are free to disagree.  `Program-Files` isn't a standard directory.

Comment: The symptoms may not be identical in the proposed duplicate, but the same underlying problem could be the root cause.  Check out the answers to see if one solves the problem.  Problems don't always manifest the same way on different computers.

Comment: I had actually checked those answers before posting this question. They were pretty much irrelevant for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that I have come up with in a similar situation: **to uninstall & re-install Java**.

It's possible that this issue has something to do with what happens when Java update loads a new version to your system. I am saying this because Java by default tends to install itself into directories where the directory name has the version number. So a change in version number => changes the installation directory => may have an effect on some paths were system expects to find Java.

I am not sure if this is the cause however but so as to remove that possibility, when I re-installed Java I created a custom directory `C:\Program Files\Java\JDK` (**this was the 64-bit version**; a 32-bit version should have been placed in `C:\Program Files (x86)`) and directed the installer to put everything in that directory (instead of its default which would have been something like: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_1.8.0.66`).

If you are installing just the JRE then the custom path could be something like `C:\Program Files\Java\JRE` (instead of the default `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8`).

When you uninstall Java, make sure that:

- The Java directories (in either `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` or `C:\Program Files\Java`) are actually deleted by the uninstaller. If not, it's better to delete them manually (since you will be re-installing them anyway, this should be fine).
- Any environment variables (e.g. JAVA_HOME, PATH, etc) that refer to the old location actually point to the new location

Comment: Thanks I think I will go with the uninstall & re-install. Does not really tell me why it happened but maybe it was because of what you say (the update process).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just copied `javacpl.cpl` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\javacpl.cpl` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`. Next time I opened the control panel the Java applet was visible again.